# WebServer: Send file that is still being written

Tags: nginx, php, http

I have a long-running process that creates large files for a web application that are stored in the file system.

Is there a way to deliver the download of this file via the web server (currently nginx) without ending the download if the file created up to that point has been downloaded and then waiting for the file to be created further?

At the moment there is always a wait until the file is complete, but therefore the download starts much later.

Kind Regards

Comment: How should server know that file creation is completed?

Comment: The web server should recognize this through file locking. As an alternative, I thought about putting a file next to it that says that the file is ready (e.g. xx.ready).

I could also do that using PHP, but it is not very performant and always blocks a PHP thread